# Avoiding dependency beetween presentation layer and DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I'm writing a simple web application and I encountered on an architectural problem. Let's say there is a Customer class in my BLL layer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Person PersonalData { get; set; }

    public int? MaximalPrice { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        PersonalData = new Person();
    }
}
```

I am going to divide creation of data of this class into two stages. In first stage user will give basic information about the customer, that he will be able to complete later. So I created two views in my presentation layer. One that will display just basic information, second for all.

Basic:

```
 <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TelephoneNumber, new {id = "icon_telephone", mask = "telephoneNumber"})
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TelephoneNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">credit_card</i>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaximalPrice, new { id = "credit_card" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaximalPrice)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">note</i>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Note, new { id = "note_add" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Note)
    </div>
</div>
```

Full (part of view):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Street)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Street)
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BirthDate)
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TelephoneNumber , new { mask = "telephoneNumber" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TelephoneNumber)
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I made an assumption that when user will create a basic version of customer he will not be able to see it on full data customer list, and when he complete customer data, he will not be able to see it on the basic customer list.
In order to achieve it, I am considering two solutions.

1. Creating function in BLL that will iterate over all properties of my class and check if there is any of property that is not basic that is already not empty.
2. Extend DAL domain of Customer and add column that will indicate whether the customer is "basic" or "full"

But none of above solutions are perfect. First will have slow performance in big data set, because of iterating over all properties of all Customer entries. So It seems that this what should be avoided.
I don't like second options, that seems to solve this problem because it creates a dependency between presentation layer and data access layer. I feel that creating additional another column in the database only for presentation purposes is not a good idea.

So, my question is: are there any better alternatives? What do you think about this options? How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Adding a new column in the db, to determine if customer is basic or not, is not a bad idea. That will enable you to filter such customers at many other places too such as reports. Other option is to filter based on any other column which can determine if customer is basic. Let say Firstname is null for basic customer but it is never null for full customer. All in all you should do filtering of customers on some criteria instead of checking all the property values.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will choose the second option. What do you think about putting that logic into basic customer modelview in presentation layer?

Comment: You should have that logic in repository layer or data access layer where you filter the records. You should have separate methods to retrieve basic customers and full customers and call appropriate method to populate respective viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

3. DAL should be able to filter columns like `DAL.Custumers.Get(_columns_)` and BLL makes decisions according to which user type logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Create ViewModels for both the basic form and the full form. Say.. BasicInfoFormViewModel and FullInfoViewModel, with only the properties included in their specific form.

When submitting the forms, in the controller action, map the view model data to the Customer class (or whatever class you are using as an entity), and save the entity.

I don't think you need to extend the domain to indicate whether the customer is basic or full. You could simply have some service layer logic that checks the entity and determines basic/full status. Your views would use this determination to display the necessary form.